# terminal server logs off immediately after login

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-terminal-services

Windows 2003 Data Center edition, member of a domain. 1 user out of over 30 is unable to log in: it logs him off before ever showing the desktop.

Previously, I deleted his profile and then he was able to log in again (which created a new profile for him). Then a few days later it happened again, I tried gpupdate, which worked for a few days. today, it's happening again. Now, neither deleting his profile nor running gpupdate is helping.

I can see "Loading Personal Settings" and "Applying Personal Settings" and then the Remote Desktop Connection client closes.

The Event log shows nothing unusual: Zero entries in Application and System. Security shows the usual:

8/7/2012 8:58:27 AM Successful Logon
8/7/2012 8:58:27 AM Special privileges assigned to new logon
8/7/2012 8:58:28 AM User Logoff:
    User Name:  [username]
    Domain:     [domain]
    Logon ID:       (0x0,0x137FD94C)
    Logon Type: 10

of course, even if I WANTED to log off as fast as possible, I couldn't do it in 1 second.

Both users are in the Administrators group.

Anyone have any ideas?

thanks,
-wes

Comment: Any login scripts in play?

Comment: The only time I've ever seen a logoff as quickly as what you're describing was when the startup application was set to logoff.exe.

Comment: any place I should check aside from the user's Startup folder?

Comment: update: user is able to log in on the local console of the same server without trouble.

Comment: similar problem: windows server 2012 R2, two domain users can login via rdp, two others exhibit the problem. one of them (me) can login to other servers w/o any problem. I cannot login locally with the domain users either.